# I can not receive any data at kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

At Kibana I receive this error:

> Saved "field" parameter is now invalid. Please select a new field.

I can not receive any data at Kibana. NOTE: The parameter times is not searchable neither aggregatable.

[image: Index patter kibana]

My index created at elasticseach is like that:

[image]

I add all information because I don't know where is the error exactly.

I'm new in that field. I'm sending data to aws iot, and after that I send to elastichsearch, at iot i receive that:

```
{"location" : "6960,6960", "times" : "2017-04-30 18:22:55"}
```

Comment: Have you indexed data into index? Can you confirm that data exists for `times` field in index?

Comment: I'm new in that field. I'm sending data to aws iot, and after that I send to elastichsearch, at iot i receive that:
{"location" : "6960,6960", "times" : "2017-04-30 18:22:55"}

Comment: Can you share results of following command `GET /_cat/indices?v` (you should execute it on kibana `Dev Tools` window)

Comment: the results:    health status index    uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .kibana  N00McocVSN-22q1CAepSJw   1   1          2            0      8.2kb          8.2kb
yellow open   testgps1 V5J3NYE6QiyJhaf2xfaEdw   5   1          0            0       650b           650b

Comment: `doc.count` is `0` for `testgps` index i.e documents are not getting indexed. Check your indexing code! It's failing to index documents.